# "I am on the street" or "I am in the street"?

Tags: prepositions

[This site](http://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/in-on-at-prepositions-place) says

> "**IN**" tells us the noun is in an enclosed space (surround or closed
>   off on all sides). Basically, when something is inside something.
>
> "**AT**" tells us that the following noun is located at a specific
>   point or location. It shows an exact position.
>
> "**ON**" tells us that the following noun is located on a surface. Use on when
>   one thing is attached to or touching something.

But, what about:

"*I am in the street*" (so, the street is considered as an enclosed space, maybe, the sentence would mean I am in the middle of the street, not on a pavement)? or

"*I am on the street*" (so, the street is considered as a surface, the sentence would mean I am standing on it, not under the ground)?

**What are the differences?**

Comment: "In the street" implies to me that you have somehow found yourself inside of the pavement (crater, digging, fusion experiment gone awry, etc.), but that might just be me.

Comment: @Alexander - Consider the song ["Dancing In the Street"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_in_the_Street) - clearly Marvin Gaye didn't mean to imply "dancing while embedded in the blacktop".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I am **in** the street.

usually means you are on the pavement of the street possibly where you can get hit by  car, as one would tell children "Get **out** of the street!"

> I am **at** the street.

is usually used to say you have arrived *at* a street e.g. an intersection with another street "I am at Fifth Avenue and 43rd St."

> I am **on** the street.

is used to say you somewhere along the street "He lives **on** Mitchell Avenue." means he lives somewhere along Mitchell Avenue.

Answer (score 1):

"I am in the street" is definitely more generic that "I am on Elm Street". "In" is more general statement about you being out of doors, perhaps homeless; whereas "On" is more specific to a particular street.

Answer (score 0):

Marvin Gaye's song "Dancing in the street" infers that they are in the middle of the street.

The correct form is stated above. When you use **in** you are referring to being **on the middle of the street** or literally inside or under the street. But then we would just say I'm in the sewer under the street.

Kids can play **in** the street. They can also play **on** the street. They **cannot** play **at** the street.

Comment: In UK English, "I am on the street" usually means "I am homeless".