# ON. / IN the street - meaning (example)

Tags: prepositions

As far as I know:

He was living **on the street**.
= he was a homeless

He was dancing **on the street** like a maniac.
= he was dancing on the pavement

If it is correct, how would **"in"** instead of **"on"** change it for?

Comment: Use *on the street* if the object is expected to be on the street.  Use *in the street* if the object is not expected to be on the street.  A car driving in front of you is *on the street*.  A stalled car blocking traffic is *in the street*.  If you block traffic when you live on the street, you are *living in the street*.  We often add *in **the middle of** the street* to further indicate the object is blocking the street, even though the object may not physically be in the *exact* middle.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between '*in*' and '*on*' is subtle. As a general rule, if A is in B, A is surrounded or enclosed by B; if A is on B, A is above and physically supported by B.

However, in expressing location, as [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/129892/i-am-on-the-street-or-i-am-in-the-street?noredirect=1&lq=1) points out, to be "*in* the street" usually means to be in the middle of the street--often in the road where cars drive. To be "*on* the street" literally means to just to be standing in the street, but it also has an idiomatic meaning: to be homeless.

If you replace '*on*' with '*in*' in the sentences you give, they suggest:

> He was living **on** the street.

He was homeless.

> He was living **in** the street.

To my ear this suggests that he was not only homeless, but living in the middle of the road (where cars drive), or some other unsafe place. You might use this if you want to emphasize how unfortunate the person's living conditions are. It may also literally mean he is living inside of the street, for example in the sewers, but this is probably not any listener's first thought.

> He was dancing **on** the street like a maniac.

This is correct, but draws particular attention to the street itself; it suggests that the pavement or the location is important. Perhaps he is interacting with the pavement in an usual way, like by stomping on it; perhaps he usually dances on hardwood but is now dancing on the concrete.

> He was dancing **in** the street like a maniac.

This is also correct, but suggests that the dancer is dancing in the road (where cars drive). To my ear this suggests greater movement, perhaps across or down the street. Of the two this is more informal and probably the more natural.